Applescript error, error in on message received
on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data) -- (string, file path as string, boolean)
    try
        set the target_file to the target_file as text
        set the open_target_file to ¬
            open for access file target_file with write permission
        if append_data is false then ¬
            set eof of the open_target_file to 0
        write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof
        close access the open_target_file
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file target_file
        end try
        return false
    end try
end write_to_file

using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat
        write_to_file(theMessage, "message.txt", False)
        write_to_file(theBuddy, "person.txt", False)
        return
    end message received
end using terms from application "Messages"

when i attempt run this code, it says
Expected “given”, “into”, “with”, “without” or other parameter name but found identifier.
when it gets to the on message received block
idk what to do,please help.

What OS are you running?  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318230/did-apple-remove-the-applescript-handler-option-in-macos-high-sierra

im on sonoma 14.1

so its gone?? but i can still send messages with applescript tho so idk

Remove application "Messages" from the last line. The entire line should be end using terms from; the same way that the end tell statement doesn't include the specific application. As an aside, when you are closing a block (eg tell, if..then, try, repeat, or using terms from) you can just type end and when you compile, the compiler will complete the line appropriately.

Ok, I fixed it but it still has the same error. Thank you for the tip.

The message received command requires three parameters, the last of which is with. It's telling you, in a cryptic manner, to complete the command. While I can't say that it's particularly helpful in this case, you can see the command syntax in the dictionary (File > Open Dictionary… then select the Messages app).

@Mockman - Without AppleScript handler support (which was apparently removed a while back), message received is not a valid handler declaration.

So no more Messages Applescript D:

@red_menace Seems weird that it would give such an error message.

@Mockman - Unless the terminology is declared in the scripting dictionary, I am guessing that AppleScript is assuming labeled parameters, which require the use of one of the pre-defined labels or given, with/out, etc.

I removed the using terms from commands and ran just the handler and that's what happened. I removed the word received… same error. I inserted first with and then into and the code was compiled as a standard handler. I guess you're right.
